# asp.net button is not function in div and table for ui dialog

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, button

I am having error for asp.net button is not function with my `VS 2010`: 
When I remove the `ui-dialog` everything is working fine. 
I need one advice from all of you: 
Below is the Dropbox link to the source file: 
    Click [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/egeeo1rxovw3vpl/WebSite1.rar)

Comment: You can do this thing also with `ModalPopupExtender`. If I am not wrong you want to open a pop up and than create new user in that or cancel ? Is it ?

Comment: @AfnanAhmad (Y) yes, did you have any link for `ModalPopupExtender`

Comment: posting my answer for `ModalPopupExtendar`. Try it.

Comment: @AfnanAhmad sorry link please :)

Comment: Most people at stack do not like links so I have posted my answer please review it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your problem:-

Register Assembly `AjaxControlToolkit`

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

Add `ModalPopUpEntender` like following:

```
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
<cc3:ModalPopupExtender ID="Modal1" BehaviorID="Modal1" runat="server"
 TargetControlID="HiddenField1" PopupControlID="Panel2" Enabled="true" BackgroundCssClass="modalBg">
</cc3:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Style="display: none; border-top-width: thin;
border-left-width: thin; border-left-color: black; border-bottom-width: thin;
border-bottom-color: black; border-top-color: black; border-right-width: thin;
border-right-color: black;" Width="350px" >
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
 <tr>
   <td>
    <asp:Button ID="imgbtnSaveSearch" CausesValidation="False" runat="server" Text="Save Record"
        CssClass="yourCssClass" OnClick="imgbtnSave_Click"/>
    <asp:Button ID="ImageButtonCancel" runat="server" OnClick="imgbtnCancel_Clikc"
        Text="Cancel" CssClass="button" />
     </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</asp:Panel>
```

Show it at button click:-

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnShow" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
                                    ImageUrl="~/Images/your image.gif"   OnClick="imgbtnShow_Click" />
```

Code Behind Code for Buttons Click:-

```
     protected void imgbtnShow_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
            {
                Modal1.Show();
            }
    protected void imgbtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
            {
               // do stuff here to save data
            }
protected void imgbtnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Modal1.Hide();
}
```

Css Class for making everything disable when pop up appears:-

```
.modalBg
        {
            background-color: #D3D3D3; /* IE 8 */
            -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)"; /* IE 5-7 */
            filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* Netscape */
            -moz-opacity: 0.5; /* Safari 1.x */
            -khtml-opacity: 0.5; /* Good browsers */
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
```